# Navigate to same url on page refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

I setup my AuthGuard to prevent pages from being accessible with users not logged in or users without the required roles/permissions.

For the most part, it is working just fine. There's just the minor issue where on page refresh, the user gets redirected to log in page, which is the main page.

I found the issue that the user is not authenticated on refresh. I've setup some logic to check if user is the right role or exists, if so, check user permissions, else go back to sign up page.

My only question is.... I'm not sure how to get the same url/route before the page refreshed.

Here's my setup so far:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  userPermissions;
  returnUrl: string;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private userService: AuthenticationService,
     private rout: ActivatedRoute) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      .then((authenticated: boolean) => {
        if (authenticated) {
          return true;
        } else {
         // this.router.navigate(['/']);
         const user = localStorage.getItem('username');
         console.log(user);
         this.userService.getUserPermissions(user).subscribe(data => {
             this.userPermissions = data;
             this.checkUserPermissions();
         }, (err) => {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
         });
        }
      });
  }

  checkUserPermissions() {
    if (this.userPermissions._userPermissions._userPrivilegeKey === 100) {
            localStorage.setItem('userRole', 'Sales');
            // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
          this.returnUrl = this.rout.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
            return true;

    } else if (this.userPermissions._userPermissions._userPrivilegeKey === 400) {
              localStorage.setItem('userRole', 'Admin');
              this.returnUrl = this.rout.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
              this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
              return true;
    }
  }
}
```

I looked into setting up a snapshot from ActivatedRoute  which will fetch the returnUrl/Url before page refresh but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to set that up?

Do I initialize a setup in my main components ngOnIt() or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can  get the current route using state.url and passing it to checkUserPermissions function  that way:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
  .then((authenticated: boolean) => {
    if (authenticated) {
      return true;
    } else {
     // this.router.navigate(['/']);
     const user = localStorage.getItem('username');
     console.log(user);
     this.userService.getUserPermissions(user).subscribe(data => {
         this.userPermissions = data;
         this.checkUserPermissions(state.url);
     }, (err) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
     });
    }
  });
  }


checkUserPermissions(url) {
if (this.userPermissions._userPermissions._userPrivilegeKey === 100) {
        localStorage.setItem('userRole', 'Sales');
        // get return url from route parameters or default to '/
        this.router.navigate([url]);
        return true;

} else if (this.userPermissions._userPermissions._userPrivilegeKey === 400) {
          localStorage.setItem('userRole', 'Admin');
          this.router.navigate([url]);
          return true;
}
 }
```

Comment: state: RouterStateSnapshot you have it as a parameter in your canActivate function, you can return the current url, by state.url, i tried it and it works

Comment: So I tried it and you're right, it returns the right url (state.url). The only issue is doesn't properly load the page. It loads the correct url initallly then redirect to '/#/' (I am using HashLocationStrategy, so not sure if that could be affecting it?)

Comment: try this.router.navigateByUrl(url); in place of  this.router.navigate([url]);

Comment: no same issue, it's odd that it directs from e.g. /#/items to /#/ a sec later.

Comment: IT seems to be an issue with getting the user from localStorage. It says, user is not defined after it successfully reload it the first time.

Comment: ok because i'm using that solution and it woks for me, it should work

Comment: Ok I found the issue was in isAuthenticated() method. I added my fix and now it works. Thank you!